# Orchestration of lxc/ldxd containers

Tags: linux, lxc

In Docker you have a docker compose tool, with which you can set up an architecture and spin it up. Is there something likewise for lxd/lxc ?

Answer (score 0):

The people of Canonical provide [Juju](https://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/juju), which is kind-of what I am looking for. See if you can render an lxc-cloud via Juju, in which every lxc container is a Docker server.

You can start Docker in an lxc container with a command along the lines of:

```
lxc launch -p docker -p default images:ubuntu u1
```

I'm not sure where to go from here (yet).